# How does a piece of closure work within a UITableViewCell definition?

Tags: uitableview, closures, swift2

The following code snippet was retrieved from an on-line tutorial:

```
typealias TableCellConfigurationBlock = (cell: ScheduleTableViewCell, indexPath: NSIndexPath, session: Session) -> ()
```

The 'typealias' appears to be a closure; or a tuple yielding a void()?

But I don't know how it works within the following function:

```
   func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ScheduleTableViewCell") as! ScheduleTableViewCell
        let session = sessionForIndexPath(indexPath)
        if let configureBlock = tableCellConfigurationBlock {
            configureBlock(cell: cell, indexPath: indexPath, session: session)
        }
        return cell
    }
```

Explanation?

References?

Answer (score 1):

```
typealias ClosureType = (i: Int, s: String, d: Double)->String

let c1: ClosureType = {
    // has three input parameters 
    // i:Int, s: String, d: Double
    // and returns String
    i, s, d in
    return s + " integer: \(i) and double: \(d)"
}
let c2: ClosureType = {
    $1 + " integer: \($0) and double: \($2)"
}
print(c1(i: 1,s: "You pass in",d: 3.14))
print(c2(i: 1,s: "You pass in",d: 3.14))
/*
You pass in integer: 1 and double: 3.14
You pass in integer: 1 and double: 3.14
*/
```

Comment: Nicely put.  Succinct.
I played with it in 'myPlayground'.